# Dynamically Copy Range of Cells from Closed Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a range of cells in a closed notebook that does not have a static set of rows. I would like to copy it into an active workbook.

I am trying to dynamically copy all entries under the column of F from file 'test.xlsx' from the 'exception' worksheet. The macro runs without issue if there I use static referencing instead. Here is the code that I am running, it gives me a runtime error for the line that copies the data.

```
Sub GetClassID()

Dim App As New Excel.Application

Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Set wsActive = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

Dim wbImport As Workbook
Set wbImport = App.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Test.xlsx", 
UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=True)

wbImport.Worksheets("Exception").Range("F2",Range("F2").end(xldown)).Copy
wsActive.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
wsActive.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

App.CutCopyMode = False
wbImport.Close SaveChanges:=False
App.Quit

End Sub
```

Error I get is runtime erorr '1004': Interface not registered

Comment: This might be a reference error, but separately you might need to clarify the range of the `...End(xlDown)` range:  `wbImport.Worksheets("Exception").Range("F2",wbImport.Worksheets("Exception").Range("F2").end(xldown)).Copy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you run this in an Excel VBA? You don't need to open the other workbook as an `Excel.Application`, just remove the `app` out of it and open the workbook normally:

```vb
Sub GetClassID()

Dim wsActive As Worksheet
Set wsActive = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Another Sheet Name")

Dim wbImport As Workbook
Set wbImport = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Test.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=True, ReadOnly:=True)

With wbImport.Worksheets("Exception")
    .Range("F2", .Range("F2").End(xlDown)).Copy
End With
wsActive.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
wsActive.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

App.CutCopyMode = False
wbImport.Close SaveChanges:=False
App.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: I used this code and it worked no problem. However, I want to repeat this exact set of commands for another sheet, but it doesn't work. The values will copy over for a split second and disappear. What do I need remove/change from the code provided to be able to be used to perform the same actions on a different sheet?

Comment: @Wayne_Chen change `Set wsActive = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` to `Set wsActive = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Another Sheet Name")`, see updated code with this change.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the most effective way to copy a dynamic range is to create a variable as an integer and assign the row of the last cell to be copied (or column if needing to select a row of data across to a certain point. I usually accomplish it with something like this:

```
Dim R as Integer
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Then you can plug in 'R' for the row number in a range to make it dynamic each time the macro is ran. For instance: `.Range("A1:A" & R).Copy` would copy the used range in Column A. It also makes it really easy to reference the last row for loops and such continuously throughout your code. Hope this helps!